# How to save manytomany according to order of the List in Spring Data Jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa

There're my model code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jade")
public class Jade extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "jade_feature", 
     joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "jade_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, 
     inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "feature_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private List<Feature> features;

}
```

When I save the model, the data of List weren't saved according to the List's add method.

For example：

```
List<Feature> features = new ArrayList<Feature>();
features.add(a);
features.add(b);
features.add(c);
Jade jade = new Jade(features);
jade.saveAndFlush();
```

But the database data were 【c, a, b】Like this inserted.
How to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make use of **@OrderColumn** to maintain order of the List collection .

Please have a look at the docs below:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html